# Displaying in Listbox Items collections of collections. [possible HierachicalDataTemplate]

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm binding Data class to DataContext.
Data class has collection of Parents, each Parent has collection of Childrens.

Problem is easy to describe how to display in ListBox all Childrens, without displaying Parents?

Here is my sample class:

```cs
 public class Data : ObservableCollection<Parent>
    {
        public Data()
        {
            Parent p1 = new Parent();
            p1.ParenName = "A1";
            p1.Childrens.Add(new Children
            {
                ChildrenName = "Children-1",
                ChildrenCode = "A1-1"
            });
            p1.Childrens.Add(new Children
            {
                ChildrenName = "Children-2",
                ChildrenCode = "A1-2"
            });
            Parent p2 = new Parent();
            p2.ParenName = "A2";
            p2.Childrens.Add(new Children
            {
                ChildrenName = "Children-3",
                ChildrenCode = "A2-1"
            });
            p2.Childrens.Add(new Children
            {
                ChildrenName = "Children-4",
                ChildrenCode = "A2-2"
            });

            this.Add(p1);
            this.Add(p2);
        }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            this._childrens = new ObservableCollection<Children>();
        }

        string _parenName;

        public string ParenName
        {
            get { return _parenName; }
            set { _parenName = value; }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Children> _childrens;

        public ObservableCollection<Children> Childrens
        {
            get { return _childrens; }
            set { _childrens = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Children
    {
        string _childrenName;

        public string ChildrenName
        {
            get { return _childrenName; }
            set { _childrenName = value; }
        }

        string _childrenCode;

        public string ChildrenCode
        {
            get { return _childrenCode; }
            set { _childrenCode = value; }
        }
    }
```

And XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="ListBoxSample">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="parent">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ParentName}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Parent}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource parent}"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can someone tell me how to do it using HierahicalDataTemplate?

Comment: You want to show flat list of child collection or in some hierarchy?

Comment: Hello, I need to show flat list of child collection.

Comment: Check the answer please and see if that serves your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HierachicalDataTemplate` is for `TreeView`. If you want to show it in ListBox create a `wrapper property containing flat list for children` and bind your ListBox with that wrapper property.

Or

Use `IValueConverter` to flatten your collection which will return list of children.

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var parentList = value as ObservableCollection<Parent>;
        var childCollection = new ObservableCollection<Children>();
        if (parentList != null)
        {
            childCollection = new ObservableCollection<Children>
                                 (parentList.SelectMany(p => p.Childrens));
        }
        return childCollection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

XAML -

Create an instance of converter and use it for binding it with ItemsSource -

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Parent,
                         Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
         DisplayMemberPath="ChildrenName"/>
```